# Auth: Is there a way to access error.userInfo[FIRAuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey]?

Tags: react-native-firebase

I'm running into trouble using Apple Login with anonymous user.

1. signInWithCredential with apple login
2. log out
3. signin with anonymous user
4. try  linkWithCredential with apple creds; fails (expected)
5. try signInWithCredential with the same creds; fails (unexpected)

The reason why step 5 fails is because the same creds cannot be used by Apple Login twice. The problem is discussed in this [firebase IOS thread](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4434)

The solution as per that thread is to signin with a different credentials provided in

`error.userInfo[FIRAuthErrorUserInfoUpdatedCredentialKey]`

However, I do not know how to access this in react-native-firebase/auth

Can someone suggest whether this is possible with the current API?